# Comparing String Captured in Application to Regex pattern in code with two different expected languages

Tags: c#, regex, string, comparison, string-comparison

I am working on an application that has several language options. 
The problem I am encountering is coming up with an efficient way to verify the text on the screen.

The text will either be *1 of 10* or *1 de 10* depending on the language

I was attempting to do something along the lines of

```
string availableDesignCountText = designSelectionPage.designSelectionAvailableDesignCountText.Text.ToLower().Trim();
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(availableDesignCountText, @"^[\d]\s(of|de)\s[\d]");
```

*availableDesignCountText* would be the value captured from the application (1 of 10 or 1 de 10).

I would ultimately like to do an assertEquals that would compare the string to the regex pattern and would work for either language. Maybe something like

```
TestReporter.assertEquals(availableDesignCountText, expectedText, //regex maybe?
                "The Design Selection Page Available Design Text [" + closeButtonText + "] " +
                "Didn't Match the Expected Text [" + expectedText + "]");
```

Any Recommendations?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `@"^\d+\s+(?:of|de)\s+\d+$"`

Comment: If commas or decimal points are expected, then above regex may not work.  Do you expect decimal points and commas in the numbers ?

Comment: No I'm not expecting either of those

Comment: @Niko please share some more possible matches that you are expecting here. Without the context of the domain of values to match it would be difficult to come up with the right `regex`

Comment: @SarathSadasivanPillai that would really be the only text that would be expected. 1 of 10 / 3 of 41 / 8 de 10 / 1 de 5 / etc, etc. I'm trying to verify that the string has any number before the "of|de" and any number after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            // Available Design Count Text
            addTestStep("The Design Selection Available Design Text Matches the Expected Text");
            string availableDesignCountText = designSelectionPage.designSelectionAvailableDesignCountText.Text.ToLower().Trim();
            bool textMatches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(availableDesignCountText, @"^\d+\s+(?:of|de)\s+\d+$");
            TestReporter.assertTrue(textMatches,
                "The Design Selection Page Available Design Text Didn't Match the Expected Format [" + availableDesignCountText + "]");
            addTestStep("Complete");
```

This ended up doing the trick!